# Memory Leak in C# Clock

Tags: c#, memory, clock

I have a memory leak in this C# project. It is an analog clock and the memory usage is increasing from second to second. Which error has been hidden?

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
            int Hour = Now.Hour;
            int Minute = Now.Minute;
            int Second = Now.Second;

            Single AngleS = Second * 6;
            Single AngleM = Minute * 6 + AngleS / 60;
            Single AngleH = Hour * 30 + AngleM / 12;

            backBox.Image = back;
            backBox.Controls.Remove(backBox);
            backBox.Controls.Add(hourBox);

            hourBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            hourBox.Image = rotateImage(hour, AngleH);
            hourBox.Controls.Add(minuteBox);

            minuteBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            minuteBox.Image = rotateImage(minute, AngleM);
            minuteBox.Controls.Add(dotBox);
            
            dotBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            dotBox.Image = dot;
            dotBox.Controls.Add(secondBox);
            
            secondBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            secondBox.Image = rotateImage(second, AngleS);
        }
```

Comment: You keep adding `Controls`. That is probably not useful and eats memory.

Comment: Show us the code for the rotateImage() method.

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Drawing.Image` objects are `IDisposable`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=net-5.0), so you'll need to take care to `Dispose()` of any rotated images you no longer use.

Depending on your layout (which we can't see from your snippet), it might be a good idea to refactor things so you ever draw rotated things onto one image.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
        int Hour = Now.Hour;
        int Minute = Now.Minute;
        int Second = Now.Second;

        Single AngleS = Second * 6;
        Single AngleM = Minute * 6 + AngleS / 60;
        Single AngleH = Hour * 30 + AngleM / 12;

        // add this code
        // i think
        // backBox.Image.Dispose() is better but that can cause other errors
        backBox.Image = null;
        //
        backBox.Image = back;
        backBox.Controls.Remove(backBox);
        backBox.Controls.Add(hourBox);

        hourBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        
        //add this code
        hourBox.Image = null;
        //
        hourBox.Image = rotateImage(hour, AngleH);
        hourBox.Controls.Add(minuteBox);

        minuteBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        // add this code
        minuteBox.Image = null;
        //
        minuteBox.Image = rotateImage(minute, AngleM);
        minuteBox.Controls.Add(dotBox);
        
        dotBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        // add this code
        dotBox.Image = null;
        //
        dotBox.Image = dot;
        dotBox.Controls.Add(secondBox);
        
        secondBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        // add this code
        secondBox.Image = null;
        //
        secondBox.Image = rotateImage(second, AngleS);
    }
```

There is one part that concerns me

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap rotateMe, float angle)        
{             
    Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(rotateMe.Width, rotateMe.Height);   

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))  
    {                 
        g.TranslateTransform(rotateMe.Width / 2, rotateMe.Height / 2);          
        g.RotateTransform(angle);                 
        g.TranslateTransform(-rotateMe.Width / 2, -rotateMe.Height / 2);     
        g.DrawImage(rotateMe, new Point(0, 0));                             
    }
                   
    return rotatedImage;       
}
```

minuteBox.Image = rotageedImage = rotateMe = minute

so,If you put null, it may cause malfunction.
Be aware of this!

Answer (score 0):

Old image has to be disposed, so

```
    hourBox.Image = rotateImage(hour, AngleH);
```

Change to

```
    var OldImage = hourBox.Image;
    hourBox.Image = rotateImage(hour, AngleH);
    if(OldImage != null )
    {
        OldImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Do the same with minute, dot and second.